# generating function: faster generation of F(n)

Tags: algorithm

i recently gave a test... the question was long  story and the solution boiled down to 
F(n) = 2*F(n-1) + 2*F(n-2)...

I had an O(n) solution using dynamic programming... However, the examiner wasn't satisfied...

my solution was to simply store every F(n) in an array as it is calculated. it took O(n) time.
as we need just the previous two elements, by using just two variables, the space problem can be solved.

however O(n) isn't fast enough...

the function looks like the fibonacci function, and a fibonacci number can be generated in O(lg n) time... but am unable to get a O(lg n) soln for my problem..

so my question is how do i improve the time-complexity of the function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [I want to generate the nth term of the sequence 1,3,8,22,60 ,164 in Order(1) or order of (nlogn)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11301992/i-want-to-generate-the-nth-term-of-the-sequence-1-3-8-22-60-164-in-order1-or)

Comment: This looks awfully similar to a question asked a few hours ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381277/how-to-speed-up-series-generation

Comment: This is around the fifth time I see this question in the last 2-3 weeks. Some professor somewhere must really love mentioning this site in his/her lectures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Exactly the same way.  Express your recurrence in [matrix form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Matrix_form); this reduces the problem to finding the n-th power of a matrix, [which can be done in log(n) time](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring).

Answer (score 3):

There is a closed formula for any linear recurrence relation (which this is).

It involves solving the characteristic polynomial, which in this case is:

```
t^2 - 2*t - 2 = 0   (since F(n) - 2 * F(n-1) - 2 * F(n-2) = 0)
```

If t1 and t2 are the (complex) solutions of this quadratic equation, then the formula is:

```
F(n) = a * t1^n + b * t2^n
```

where a and b are constants, which can be found from the initial conditions (i.e. the values of F(0) and F(1) in this case).
I.e.

```
F(0) = a + b
F(1) = a * t1 + b * t2
```

Solving for a and b:

```
a = ( t2 * F(0) - F(1) ) / ( t2 - t1 )
b = ( t1 * F(0) - F(1) ) / ( t1 - t2 )
```

In this particular case the roots of the characteristic polynomial are:

```
t1 = 1 + sqrt(3)
t2 = 1 - sqrt(3)
```

Comment: +1 Use math when you can. (Also: nice background and explanation, giving the tools for readers how to develop these equations when possible)

Comment: An important tnote: a closed form solution does not imply a fast O(1) or O(lg n) solution. The precision required for `t1` and `t2` to calculate the n-th term grows with `n`.

Comment: @tskuzzy: Not if you're cunning.  `(a + b.sqrt(3)) * (c + d.sqrt(3)) == (e + f.sqrt(3))`, where `e == (a.c + b.d)`, `f == (a.d + b.c)`.  In other words, it can all be done with integer maths.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Wait what, I did not follow that. Where did those equations come from and what do they mean?

Comment: @tskuzzy: Your original comment was implying that the irrational/fractional nature of sqrt(3) would be a problem, due to precision limitations.  My comment is pointing out that it's not a problem.  The equations I gave are just an example; they illustrate that it's possible to handle algebra on sqrt(3) with integer arithmetic only.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: But it is a problem in this case. In the closed-form expression, the irrational `1 +/- sqrt(3)` is being raised to the nth power. You cannot trivially simplify it further with integer arithmetic. But an interesting point here is that the matrix method is actually doing all of this irrational math if you consider the eigenvalues of the matrix.

Comment: @tskuzzy: Yes, you can!  `(1 + sqrt(3))^2 == (4 + 2.sqrt(3))`, `(1 + sqrt(3))^3 == (10 + 6.sqrt(3))`, etc.  It's all integer arithmetic.  You just need two coefficients to represent each quantity, one for the integer component, and one for the sqrt(3) component.  And as the solution must eventually be an integer, you'll find that the sqrt(3) coefficient will cancel to zero at the end.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: If you raise to the n-th power, that gives `n+1` terms for each binomial expansion which is no better than the normal iterative solution.

Comment: @tskuzzy: `n+1` terms?  There are O(log(n)) operations required, which makes it equivalent to the matrix operation in my answer.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: How are there `lg n` operations? `(1+sqrt(3))^n` has `n+1` terms if want to use the integer arithmetic that you described. If you want to do exponentiation by squaring, you run into the precision problem that I described. What I'm saying is that there's no trivial way to evaluate the closed-form solution.

Comment: @tskuzzy: you can still do exponentiation-by-squaring with the two-coefficient approach.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You can't do it more efficiently than linear time since the size of the output is already `O(n)`. e.g. `(1+pi)^3 = 1+3pi + 3pi^2 + pi^3`.

Comment: @tskuzzy: You don't need to represent each term individually.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: How else would you do it? Without having each term, you can't perform the integer arithmetic that you described.

Comment: @tskuzzy: Let `i = sqrt(3)`.  `(1 + i)^2 == (4 + 2i)`.  `(1 + i)^4 == (4 + 2i)^2 == (28 + 16i)`.  `(1 + i)^8 == (28 + 16i)^2`.  etc.  Only two terms are propagated in each step.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I need to get more sleep... Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 0):

In your solution, you also used O(n) memory.

You can use simple loop to calculate the n-th Fibonacci element:

The only thing you need to save is the 3 (a1,a2,a3) last elements, in each iteration you update a1 to be a2, update a2 to be a3, and update a3 to be old(a1) + old(a2) (you can use 2 temp vars for this purpose).

So we get simple algorithm with run-time O(n) only O(1) memory.

Comment: The OP is asking about improving the time complexity, not the space complexity...